# Is it possible to have a pond that doesn't require a pump for circulation?

Tags: landscaping

So I'm trying to build a garden pond but I don't have any power. Is it possible to have a pond that doesn't require a pump for circulation? I do plan on having fish and so plants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A google search for "solar powered fish pond filters" shows many sources. Since you didn't mention the size of your pond or geographic area I didn't make any specific suggestions. But there is a wealth of info and products out there.

Comment: The pond is only a 3 or 4 foot diameter and 3 feet deep